# Coworkers lying to supervisor

Tags: colleagues, lying

When in a staff meeting the other day two of my coworkers lied to my supervisor,  and said it was another departments fault that their work is not getting done. I feel like I have a responsibility to tell my supervisor that she is being lied to. Especially since other people are being unfairly blamed.

I do not know how to go about it though because  in terms of hierarchy at the workplace I am the lowest, and my job was only temporary and ends in a week. But I do not think that any of my other coworkers who were in the meeting would report it because I have caught them saying the same sorts of things, just not directly to my supervisor.

Is it appropriate for me to report them, should I even bother if I am am only there for another week?

Comment: Assuming you will not see these people ever again and will never work for this company, you could report them as lying is wrong. However, this will not gain you anything, and could result in your coworkers' employment to be terminated. Therefore you have to weight the pros and cons.

Comment: Do you have any proof? Do you have reason to believe the co-workers in the other department can't defend themselves against these claims?

Comment: To add to what @BSMP asks, are you sure the manager doesn't already know they were lying, or that they have lied in the past?

Comment: If he lied and the others get blamed once, they won't get twice, they'll cover their back next time and your coworker is gonna have troubles.

Comment: If it doesn't affect you, stay out of it.

Answer (score 6):

If I were the supervisor I'd definitely want to know. I would arrange to have a chat with your supervisor just before you leave (ideally last day if you can manage it). If you have any evidence of the lie make sure you take it with you, if you don't have any evidence then make sure you report it as a *suspicion* only.

Stress that you aren't wanting to throw anyone under a bus but you are just letting the supervisor know what you know.

Answer (score 1):

If I found myself in this situation I would respond *in the meeting* to correct the falsehood by presenting any information I had to rebut the lie.

This is at least above board, insofar as the liar knows exactly what you said, and everyone can respond in real time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate for me to report them, should I even bother if I am
>   am only there for another week?

That depends. Do you think your supervisor will actually lend credence to your report, or do you have specific proof? If so, you should definitely say something in your exit interview, or if there isn't one maybe in a private chat with your supervisor on your last day.

It also depends if you like the company and/or your supervisor enough to want to tell them, but yes, generally you should mention it, at least somewhere, but only if you're absolutely sure they were lying and you can point to some facts to support that. You don't want to make accusations that don't go anywhere, as that could jeopardize future references.

If I was the supervisor I would definitely want to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate for me to report them, should I even bother if I am
>   am only there for another week?

Yes, why not turn them in at this point **as long as you have proof**?  Present your evidence in a *factual way*, and do not get personal with it.  As a supervisor I would appreciate your honesty.

They key to this is **evidence**.  If you don't have any, keep it to yourself as your the one on the way out the door and it will come across as sour grapes.

Comment: "sour grapes"?  It was a temporary appointment that has reached the end of its term.  The OP isn't leaving in a week because of being fired.  Not sure why letting a supervisor know they are being lied to would be viewed as "sour grapes."  The OP works in the area and is familiar with the work being done.  OP heard co-workers tell supervisor things that are not true, first hand. That's plenty of evidence.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet ONLY if you do this without evidence.

Comment: Ah... that pesky "context" thing.  I whiffed on that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should raise the concern to the supervisor "that people in the other department are being unfairly blamed".  Explain why you think the other department met their responsibilities.  No need to say anything negative about the suspected liars, focus on the positive side of the story, and let the supervisor connect the dots.